# Can inputing data into a formula cell be done without deleting the formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the cells within Column D on my spreadsheet I have a formula that uses the numbers in the cells in Column C to calculate an answer.

However, I would like the option to input a number instead into the cells in Column D, which the cells in Column C would then use in their formula. The idea is not to wipe the formula in Column D out when the number is input, but to reinstate the formula when for example, a 0 (zero) is input.

I would like to use the ranges C9:C238 and D9:D238.

Is this possible?

Comment: That's not possible with standard formulas. You can write a macro which detects when `0` is entered and replaces it by the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Active_Column = 4 'Column where this macro applies
Min_Active_Row = 9 'Min row where this macro applies
Max_Active_Row = 238 ' Max row where this macro applies
Target_Row = Target.Row
Target_Column = Target.Column
If Target_Column = Active_Column Then
    If Target_Row >= MinActive_Row And Target_Row <= Max_Active_Row Then
        If Target.Value = "0" Then
            Target.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(Target_Row, 3) * 14 'Replace this with your formula
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Goto macro /VBA, click on the worksheet where you want it to work and paste it on the right side.